# How does Blood Sun and Ashaya, Soul of the Wild interact?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Related to [This question.](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/53034/how-does-ashaya-soul-of-the-wild-interact-with-blood-moon) what happens when there is a [Blood Sun](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Blood%20Sun) and [Ashaya, Soul of the Wild](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Ashaya%2C%20Soul%20of%20the%20Wild) in play? How is it different from a [Blood Moon](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Blood%20Moon)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works exactly the same, Ashaya dies immediately as a State Based Action due to being a 0/0 as she loses her ability that sets her power and toughness.

[Hackworth's answer](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/53035/22772) on the original question lays everything out pretty well, the only difference is that the cards don't become mountains, the creatures stay forests, and other non-basic lands stay as they were, with nothing but mana abilities, for the moment before all the SBAs resolve and Ashaya is removed.

One notable difference is [Rootpath Purifier](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Rootpath%20Purifier) will stop Ashaya from dying to Blood Moon, but not Blood Sun, because Blood Sun affects all lands, Blood Moon only affects non-basic lands.